# How to upload file with Asp.net Web Api project?

Tags: vb.net, rest, c#-to-vb.net

i have a web API project to be consumed from mobile applications and i was trying to make a file upload controller. there are few resources in C# and i don't find anything useful for VB.NET.

i tried this code below converting from c# to VB.NET, but says "Move is not a member of MultiPartFileData".

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Http

Namespace HelloWorld.Controller
    Public Class FileUploadingController
        Inherits ApiController

        <HttpPost>
        <Route("api/FileUploading/UploadFile")>
        Public Async Function UploadFile() As Task(Of String)
            Dim ctx = HttpContext.Current
            Dim root = ctx.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")
            Dim provider = New MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root)

            Try
                Await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)

                For Each file In provider.FileData
                    Dim name = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName
                    name = name.Trim(""""c)
                    Dim localFileName = file.LocalFileName
                    Dim filePath = Path.Combine(root, name)
                    File.Move(localFileName, filePath)
                Next

            Catch e As Exception
                Return $"Error: {e.Message}"
            End Try

            Return "File uploaded!"
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Try to specify the full namespace _System.IO.File.Move(localFileName, filePath)_ or change the name of the variable _file_ (lowercase) to something that doesn't clash with the File (uppercase) class

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means the compiler think that you are trying to call a method from the `MultiPartFileData` class. The variable of type MultiPartFileData is the one called *file* (notice the lowercase) initialized in the For Each loop.

Instead you want to call the Move method from the System.IO.File class (notice the uppercase).

VB.NET services (always running in background looking to catch errors while you type) is case insensitive so, for it, the two names are the same and here arises the error emitted when you code that line.

The best solution is to avoid names like *file* for your variables when you plan to use the class System.IO.File. Otherwise you could simply add the full qualified method's name in this way

```
System.IO.File.Move(localFileName, filePath)
```